# How To Resolve Firebase FIRFunctionsErrorCode 13 on Cloud Vision

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-vision

I am trying to implement an app that extracts text from images using Google's Cloud Vision. I followed the official guide [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml/ios/recognize-text). After I run the code it produces the following error:

```
Error Code: __C.FIRFunctionsErrorCode
Error: Error Domain=com.firebase.functions Code=13 "INTERNAL" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=INTERNAL}
```

As per the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasefunctions/api/reference/Enums/FIRFunctionsErrorCode) *Internal errors mean some invariant expected by the underlying system has been broken. If you see one of these errors, something is very broken.* But I cannot pinpoint what the error is in regards to. In the Firebase console functions log, there are no errors produced.

The text extraction function is as below:

```
func extractText(image: UIImage){
        guard let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) else { return }
        let base64encodedImage = imageData.base64EncodedString()
        
        lazy var functions = Functions.functions()
        
        let requestData = [
          "image": ["content": base64encodedImage],
          "features": ["type": "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION"],
          "imageContext": ["languageHints": ["en-t-i0-handwrit"]],
        ]

        functions.httpsCallable("annotageImage").call(requestData) { result, error in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                if error.domain == FunctionsErrorDomain{
                    let code = FunctionsErrorCode(rawValue: error.code)
                    let message = error.localizedDescription
                    let details = error.userInfo[FunctionsErrorDetailsKey]

                    print("Code is\n:\(code)")
                    print("Message is:\n\(message)")
                    print("Details:\n\(details)")
                    print("Error Complete:\n\(error)")
                    return
                }
            }
   
            guard let annotation = (result?.data as? [String: Any])?["fullTextAnnotation"] as? [String: Any] else { return }
            print("%nComplete annotation:")
            let text = annotation["text"] as? String ?? ""
            print("%n\(text)")
        }
    }
```

How can I find more information on what specifically is causing the error?

Comment: You are mixing up [callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) with normal [HTTP functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events). 
Your function is a normal HTTP function, but you're trying to call it using the Firebase library for invoking callable type functions. This won't work.The client SDK only works with callable functions as you see in the documentation. If you want to keep using a normal HTTP function, you should invoke it instead with a standard HTTP client library.  I hope this helps you.

Comment: @PriyankaKharche I don't think I understood you. The method above is not written by me. It is from the [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml/ios/recognize-text). Are you saying they have implemented it wrongly?

Comment: If you have copied the code from the documentation then it seems the base64 image data is possibly bad. Can you add printf statements in the Firebase Functions code and try to narrow down the issue?

Comment: @PriyankaKharche I am facing the same issue on my side too.